# Регулярное выражение с оператором "ИЛИ"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть 2 строки на входе

```
ТП 12-11/1000-Ф1-14/1-79-НД(3)-Б-СИП
ТП 12-11/1000-Ф1-14-79-НД(3)-Б-СИП
```

Есть регулярка, которая должна возвращать все символы до `-79`. Добавил оператор |, но почему то в первой строке получается `ТП 12-11/1000-Ф1-14`, а должно `ТП 12-11/1000-Ф1-14/1`

```
.+-Ф\d{1,3}-\d{1,4}|\d{1,4}\/\d{1,2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам тут не альтернацию использовать надо, а необязательное вхождение `(\/\d1,2{})?`

```
.+?-Ф\d{1,3}-\d{1,4}(\/\d{1,2})?
```

Comment: `ТП 13-5/250-Ф1-78-П` а почему эта регулярка для данной строки не работает?

Comment: @Radzhab вроде работает https://regex101.com/r/3LIs85/1